# Maximum number of decimals places in machine and DB

Tags: java, c++, sql, operating-system

1) is there a maximum number of decimal places for a floating point decimal number that can be stored on disk for a given machine?

2)is there a maximum number of decimal places that a given relational database management system can work with?

3)Suppose C++ code uses this exact number as stored on disk ie full decimal places. If the resulting number that C++ code outputs (eg multiply the number by 2), and the number of decimal places exceed that allowed by db, how does db handle it? Throw exception or round up to the maximum number of places allowed by the underlying hard disk?

Comment: All of this depends on the database you are using and the libraries you are using to connect to it.

Comment: With Oracle you may find that data binding works better than SQL (as this avoids conversion to string and back).

Comment: There is no one answer for every system and every database. They all adhere to their own standards. Start experimenting with your compiler and database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) is there a maximum number of decimal places for a floating point decimal number that can be stored on disk for a given machine?

Usually, the precision of a floating point number is determined by the processor or a floating point processor.

There are "Big Number" libraries that can extend the precision of a floating point number.

So, the maximum number of decimal places that can be stored on a disk depends on:
1) The size of the disk.
2) The size of the floating point implementation (such as Big Number libraries).

> 2)is there a maximum number of decimal places that a given relational database management system can work with?

Yes.  Each RDBMS has its own limits.  There is no standard limitation among the databases.  You'll have to survey the databases and find out.

> 3)Suppose C++ code uses this exact number as stored on disk ie full decimal places. If the resulting number that C++ code outputs (eg multiply the number by 2), and the number of decimal places exceed that allowed by db, how does db handle it? Throw exception or round up to the maximum number of places allowed by the underlying hard disk?

Overflow or capacity limitation depends on the floating point implementation (processor and database implementation).  Some implementations may truncate, some may round; all depends.  For databases, there is no standard among all the databases, for handling precision overflow or capacity limits.  You'll have to investigate either the database you plan to use or all the databases.

Also search the internet for "IEEE floating point standards".

Comment: You may want to search the internet for "calculation of PI", and see how they handle the storage of the number with a huge amount of decimal precision.

Comment: Thanks. By “Big Number” library I guess it’s part of OS?

Comment: No, Big Number library is not a part of OS.  There are many Big Number libraries out there, such as GMP.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) is there a maximum number of decimal places for a floating point decimal number that can be stored on disk for a given machine?

Computers to not natively store decimal places. They maintain binary digita. The maximum number of binary digits is deterimed by the process and the type of floating point value selected. The number of binary digitals limits the maximum number of decimal digits the value can be converted two with any meaning.

> 2)is there a maximum number of decimal places that a given relational database management system can work with?

THere are limits to everything on a computer. A database can either store the value natively or it can convert to its own format. If stored natively, the number of binary digits supported by the hardware is the limit. If stored in its own format, the database could select an arbitrary number of digits. That number could be very large.

> 3)Suppose C++ code uses this exact number as stored on disk ie full decimal places. If the resulting number that C++ code outputs (eg multiply the number by 2), and the number of decimal places exceed that allowed by db, how does db handle it? Throw exception or round up to the maximum number of places allowed by the underlying hard disk?

Multiplying by 2 will only increase the exponent. You will only get an exception if the exponent overflows.